# Casting arrays of a supertype to a subtype

Tags: java, arrays, casting

Is there a particular reason why this results in runtime exception instead of compile-time error in Java?

```
Object[] objects = new Object[10];
String[] strings = (String[])objects;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The check has to be done at run time because of this case:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] stringsBase = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
    Object[] objects = stringsBase;
    String[] strings = (String[])objects;
    System.out.println(strings[1]);
  }
}
```

This is a valid, working program. Without doing flow analysis, the compiler does not know whether objects references an array that was created as Object[], or one that was created as, in this case, a String[].

Comment: And _why_ doesn't the compiler handle cases like these?

Comment: Huh? The compiler handled it just fine.

Comment: To clarify, I meant: why isn't the compiler smart enough to differentiate between casting `String[] → Object[] → String[]` and, for instance, `String[] → Object[] → Integer[]`? It was meant to be a leading question. The answer, of course, is that [the JLS does not require the compiler to perform such checks.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15962032/139010)

Comment: The JLS says so pushes the issue back one level. It still leaves the question of why the JLS says so, which is what I was trying to answer. In full generality, whether we are dealing with a valid cast or not is undecidable. I suppose the JLS could have required something along the lines of the "definitely assigned" system, but it is simpler and cleaner to assume, absent strong evidence to the contrary, that the programmer writing a cast meant it, and the test should be left to run time.

Comment: @MattBall - the JLS doesn't require the implementation to do that because in many cases it would be impossible to do so (e.g. if after the first cast, the value is used as an argument to a method that reverses the cast).

Answer (score 2):

Because **this is the compile-time behavior defined by the language specification.** The short version is that an `Object[]` can be cast to a `String[]` without generating a compile-time error because an `Object` can be cast to a `String` without generating a compile-time error.

---

The long answer is just me quoting the JLS. From [the Java Language Specification § 5.5.1. Reference Type Casting:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1)

> Given a compile-time reference type S (source) and a compile-time reference type T (target), a casting conversion exists from S to T if no compile-time errors occur due to the following rules.
>   ...
>   If S is an array type SC`[]`, that is, an array of components of type SC:
>   ...
>
> - **If T is an array type TC`[]`, that is, an array of components of type TC, then a compile-time error occurs unless one of the following is true:**
>
>   - TC and SC are the same primitive type.
>   - TC and SC are reference types and type SC can undergo casting conversion to TC.

By a preceding rule in that same section on casting, `Object`s can undergo casting conversion to `String`s:

> If S is a class type:
>
> - **If T is a class type, then either |S| <: |T|, or |T| <: |S|. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.**

Just in case you were wondering:

> An expression of a reference type may undergo casting conversion to another reference type if no compile-time error occurs given the rules in [§5.5.1.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1)

---

Note that [the JLS uses `|T|` to denote the erasure of type `T`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) and also that [S :> T indicates that the supertype relation holds between S and T.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10) Therefore "|S| <: |T|, or |T| <: |S|" can be read as "the erasure of S is either a subtype, the same type, or a supertype of T."

Comment: Just out of curiosity... What about the fact that I can compile this: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); Object o = sb; Integer i = (Integer) o;` Could you explain why?  It kinda seems like this demonstrates that the above is **NOT** a special case... But I'm sure I'm mis-understanding something.

Comment: @jahroy answer has been heavily edited, but the second quote covers that.

Comment: Hmmm.. Wish I knew that notation.  But I don't really understand how that would apply anyways... I'm not trying to cast to String in my little example.  I'm trying to cast a StringBuilder to an Integer (which doesn't work at runtime, but does compile).  No worries if you don't feel like answering... Just curious.

Comment: @jahroy just added explanation of the notation, since I didn't immediately grok it myself. The JLS just doesn't require compilers to be that smart. The intermediate cast to `Object` in your muddies things for the compiler. If you really want to understand it take the time to dig through JLS §5.5.1. and 5.5.2.

Comment: This answer the begs the question. It could literally be applied to *any* question about Java behaviour: "why does Java throw a NullPointerException when I try to dereference a variable that contains `null`?  Because the JLS says it has to."  At the end of the day, a question as to why Java does something that is specified by the JLS should be interpreted as a question of why the JLS was written that particular way, otherwise it is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Casting is a fundamentally unsafe feature that Java provides for flexibility purposes.  That code generates "unchecked" warnings if your compiler settings are tuned correctly.

Comment: Meh. This is a pretty wishy-washy answer.