# How can String array references be stored in the reference variables of Object array?

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion, typecasting-operator

Please look at the code below.

```
class Use
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] result = new String[2];//{"Hello", "World"}; // compiles and run
        Object[] name = result; // compiles and run
    //  result = name; //CE
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

My understanding is that arrays in Java are independent objects, with no parent child relationship. So according to me "result" and "name" are reference variables of two completely different types of objects (i.e String[] and Object[]) that do not have any relationship. Then

1. why there is not an error in the statement "Object[] name = result;"?
2. why there is an error in the statement "result = name;"?
3. I know "Object" and "String" have a parent-child relationship. Is there any relationship between "Object[]" and "String[]"?

Comment: What if I do `name = new Integer[]{1}; result = name;`? An `Object[]` is not a `String[]`

Comment: 'Object[] name = new Integer[]{1};` is legal because Integer inherits from Object. An `Object[]` array is not the same as a `String[]` array.

Comment: See also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961962/casting-arrays-of-a-supertype-to-a-subtype

Comment: Apart from searching already existing questions and answers on SO, you find the definite answers to your questions in the ___Java Language Specification___, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer as well as up-vote it when it answers your question. In this way your question stops showing up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

`result = name` is trying to assign an Object array to a String array. You cannot assign an Object to a variable that was declared as a String, and the same goes for arrays. You cannot assign an array to a variable that was declared as an array of a different type.

`Object[] name = result` is legal because all objects inherit from the Object class, including String. You can assign a different data type to a declared variable if the what you are assigning inherits or implements the data type of the variable you are assigning to.

To gain a better understanding, look through the documentation of the Java language. It is a great resource for seeing the relationships between different classes.

Object class documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

String class documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Integer class documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: Thanks. I know "Object" and "String" have a parent-child relationship. Is there any relationship between "Object[]" and "String[]"?

Comment: relationships between arrays of objects mirror the original objects. Primitive arrays are just a construct of memory, they are not a class on their own.

Answer (score 0):

**`java.lang.Object` class is the super base class of all Java classes.** I guess that fixes your confusion. (if B extends C, it means B is a C and not C is a B.)

`result = name;` throws compilation error as they are of different types. You need to cast it to avoid compilation errors.

```
result = (String[]) name;
```

If it was another way round, `name=result` would have worked as String[] can be assigned to Object[]; not the other way.

https://javapapers.com/java/why-object-is-super-class-in-java/

Comment: I know "Object" and "String" have a parent-child relationship. Is there any relationship between "Object[]" and "String[]"?

Answer (score 0):

> How can String array references be stored in the reference variables of Object array?
>
> I know "Object" and "String" have a parent-child relationship. Is there any relationship between "Object[]" and "String[]"?

According to [JLS Section 4.10.3. Subtyping among Array Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3) `String[]` is a `Object[]` because `String` is a `Object`, and thus `Object[] name = result;` is legal.

> Why there is an error in the statement "result = name;"?

Given the above, a `Object[]` is **not** a `String[]`, that's why you'll get this error at compile-time.

```
Error:(13, 26) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object[] cannot be converted to java.lang.String[]
```

(After all, an array of objects `Object[]` can contain elements of any reference type like `String`, `Integer`, etc.)

However, based on your code "you know" that actually this `Object[] name` array only contains `Strings`. So that `Object[] name` is actually a `String[]`. So you can make it work by explicitly using a downcast, i.e. `result = (String[]) name`.

By using the downcast you explicitly state to the compiler that this type conversion is fine (because in general it wouldn't be). Should you then break "your promise" in your code by doing this

```
String[] strings = {"Hello", "World"};
Object[] objects = strings;
objects[0] = 1; // let's replace the string with an integer
strings = (String[]) objects;
```

you'll get this exception at run-time.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Integer
```